# Input voltage range and paralleling power op-amps of an IC

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-amplifier

I have the [STK411-240](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/108382/ETC/STK411-240E.html), a stereo AF power amplifier.

I also have its power supply, a heavy 60Hz transformer.

I want to combine the power of both channels into a single one.
BTL won't do because it quadruples Pd, since I cannot modify the power supply.

Arranging the channels in parallel would be the ideal solution.
Power amplifiers in parallel can easily become very unstable, possibly leading to them destroying each other.

May br this setup would work:

[image]

What I now wonder is:

Will the slave op-amp tolerate the input voltage?

The datasheet, just like the datasheets of other power amplifiers similar to this one, says nothing about input voltage.

Maybe the inputs will be fine since in this setup they are expected to experience no voltage between them?

Maybe the inputs were designed to withstand voltages within the limits of the supply rails?

Comment: Why not use two speakers and a mono input to the stereo amplifier?

Comment: That's not an op-amp.  It is an audio power amplifier.